# R - find/replace line breaks using regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to clean a bunch of .txt files in a folder using regex. I can't seem to get R to find line breaks.

This is the code I'm using. It works for character substitution, but not for line breaks.

```
gsub_dir(dir = "folder_name", pattern = "\\n", replacement = "#")
```

I've also tried \r and various other permutations. Using a plain text editor I find all the line breaks with \n.

Comment: Actually I think you would need `"\\\n"` but it's hard to test.

Comment: Like this maybe(I haven't used `cat`). `test<-paste("This is a \n","test")
test
gsub("\\\n","",test)`. Although in this case using `"\\n"` might not make a difference.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(365)` *When in doubt, keep adding slashes until it works.*

Comment: You also might see a significant speed up if you use the `fixed = TRUE` argument. You don't actually need *regex*, you're only looking for exact matches.

Comment: `"\\\n"` did not work; you are right that I don't need _regex_ for this example but I do need _regex_ + line break for the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with `xfun::gsub_dir`.

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/yihui/xfun/blob/5ac27093c7abe1fe5abb1de84734fdd0d083ba49/R/io.R#L15):

- The files are read in using `read_utf8` that basically executes `x = readLines(con, encoding = 'UTF-8', warn = FALSE)`,
- Then, `gsub` is fed with these lines, and when all replacements are done,
- The [`write_utf8` function](https://github.com/yihui/xfun/blob/5ac27093c7abe1fe5abb1de84734fdd0d083ba49/R/io.R#L29) concatenates the lines... with the LF, newline, symbol.

You need to use some custom function for that, here is "quick and dirty" one that will replace all LF symbols with `#`:

```
lbr_change_gsub_dir = function(newline = '\n', encoding = 'UTF-8', dir = '.', recursive = TRUE) {
 files = list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE, recursive = recursive)
 for (f in files) {
   x = readLines(f, encoding = encoding, warn = FALSE)
   cat(x, sep = newline, file = f)
 }
}

folder <- "C:\\MyFolder\\Here"
lbr_change_gsub_dir(newline="#", dir=folder)
```

If you want to be able to match multiline patterns, `paste`  the lines `collape`ing them with `newline` and use any pattern you like:

```
lbr_gsub_dir = function(pattern, replacement, perl = TRUE, newline = '\n', encoding = 'UTF-8', dir = '.', recursive = TRUE) {
 files = list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE, recursive = recursive)
 for (f in files) {
   x <- readLines(f, encoding = encoding, warn = FALSE)
   x <- paste(x, collapse = newline)
   x <- gsub(pattern, replacement, x, perl = perl)
   cat(x, file = f)
 }
}

folder <- "C:\\1"
lbr_gsub_dir("(?m)\\d+\\R(.+)", "\\1", dir = folder)
```

This will remove lines that follow digit only lines.

Comment: Thank you -- this works in answer to my narrow question. I still can't figure out my broader problem, which is how to use regex including line breaks over a folder of text files. I will post a new question about that.

Comment: @WillHanley Please note that all you need is to `paste`  the lines. See the updated answer.

Comment: I am still unsure how to do what I want to do--posted a question that I hope is clearer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345453/substitution-using-regex-with-line-breaks-on-a-folder-of-text-files